# Rails - Show objects related to user in form dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations, relationship

In my rails application the following relationships exist:
`user belongs_to :team` ,
`element belongs_to :team` , 
`task belongs_to :element`

A user can then create a task which belongs to an element.
When a user is creating a task, they can select the element they would like the task to belong to. How do I show only the elements that belong to the `current_user`'s team? I am using Devise to get the `current_user`.

The samples below do not work.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :element_id %>
    <%= form.select :element_id, options_for_select(Element.current_user.team_id.map{|s|[s.title, s.id]}),{ :multiple => true} %>
  </div>
```

I also tried to call the method below from the `tasks_controller.rb` file but it didnt work either

```
  def new
    @task = Task.new
    @tasks_element_dropdown = Element.current_user.team_id.map{|s|[s.title, s.id]}
  end
```

In the `tasks/_form.html.erb` file, I called the method with the code below

```
<%= form.select :element_id, options_for_select(@tasks_element_dropdown),{ :multiple => true} %>
```

When I tried the example below it does work but it displays all elements, and I only want the elements that belong to the user's team to display

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :element_id %>
    <%= form.select :element_id, options_for_select(Element.all.map{|s|[s.title, s.id]}),{ :multiple => true} %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following code, which should return the `elements`:

```
Element.current_user.team_id.map{|s|[s.title, s.id]}
```

Since you have a `user`, you can get the team: `current_user.team`
And then get the `elements` of the `team` (as long as `has_many :elements` is defined in the `Team` class): `current_user.team.elements`

Thus, the final code should be something like:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :element_id %>
  <%= form.select :element_id, options_for_select(current_user.team.elements.map{ |s| [s.title, s.id] }),{ :multiple => true} %>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it! It's working now -  thank you very much! I can't upvote yet so just leaving a comment for now.